# По клику кнопке открывается несколько раз activity

Tags: android, button

Проблема в следующем пользователь успевает несколько раз кликнуть по кнопке и открывается несколько activity или запускается какой то процесс, Я тут погулил мне выдало несколько решение

```
1)  setEnabled(false)

2)  if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000){
    return;
    }
    mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

Почему кнопка сама не блокируют кнопку, что бы пользователь не успел повторно нажать? Каким Вы способ пользуетесь? как Вы обрабатываете данные ситуацию

Comment: Никакого волшебного решения не существует. Только руками это обрабатывать. Самый простой способ `setEnabled(false)`. Или флаг, если не хотите чтобы внешний вид кнопки изменялся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что это должен делать разработчик, Вам не надо чтоб повторно нажимали, а кому-то надо.

```
1)  setEnabled(false)
```

Если это переход с одной активити на другую и первая не нужна в бэк-стеке можно вызывать

```
2)  finish(); после нажтия на кнопку.
```

3) Можно поставить флажок нажата кнопка flag = true; процесс выполнен flag = false. Ну и если true делаете return; 
Мало контекста, не понятно что происходит.

Comment: тут проблема в том что пользователь без причинно нажимает на все кнопки, и у него открывается несколько экранов, делать finish не вариант

Comment: c флагами не хотел, много кнопок, и будет много флагов, потом запутаюсь

Comment: ну сделай один флаг и в методе onClick обрабатывать нажатие только при условии что флаг false